# How can I execute script once until if becomes false? (Node.JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, integration, light

I am very new to coding, and don't know how to to quite word this questions. I am incorporating the CS:GO Game State Integration feature added recently to change Hue Lights based on what is happening in the game. The current part I am working on is a simple script that will change the first light to blue if I am on the 'CT' team. It's working fine besides the fact that it keeps telling me I'm on CT side over and over again. Is there a way I could change my script to only update if the first If statement becomes false?

Code:

```
setInterval(checkTeam, 250);

function checkTeam() {
  fs.readFile('player_team', 'utf8', function(err, teamStatus) {
    if (err) throw err;

    if(teamStatus === 'CT') {
      console.log('CT Side');
      if (currentStatus !== 'CT') {
        changeLight(1, noLights());
        currentStatus = 'CT';
      }
      if (currentStatus === 'CT') {
        changeLight(1, blueLights());
        currentStatus = 'CT';
      }
    }
    if (teamStatus === 'T'){
      console.log('T Side');
      if (currentStatus !== 'T Side') {
        changeLight(3, noLights());
      }
      if (currentStatus === 'T Side') {
        changeLight(3, orangeLights());
        currentStatus = 'T';
      }
      if (currentStatus === null) {
        changeLight(1, noLights());
      }
    }
  });
}

function changeLight(light, lightType) {
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(lightType);
  http.request({
    host: HUE_BRIDGE_IP,
    path: HUE_PATH + 'lights/' + light + '/state',
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': jsonString.length
    }
  }, function() {

  }).write(jsonString);
}

function redLights() {
  return {
    'on': true,
    'sat': 254,
    'bri': 254,
    'hue': 0,
    'transitiontime': 0
  }
}

function blueLights() {
  return {
    'on': true,
    'sat': 254,
    'bri': 254,
    'hue': 45000,
    'transitiontime': 0
  }
}

function explodeLights() {
  return {
    'on': true,
    'sat': 254,
    'bri': 254,
    'hue': 10000,
    'transitiontime': 0
  }
}

function whiteLights() {
  return {
    'on': true,
    'sat': 0,
    'bri': 254,
    'hue': 10000
  }
}

function noLights() {
  return {
    'on': false,
    'transitiontime': 0
  }
}

function orangeLights() {
  return {
    'on': false,
    'transitiontime': 0
  }
}
```

I'm guessing the only part you really need is the top, but just in case you needed the changeLight function, I included more. Basically, I want to get the `if(teamStatus === 'CT') {` to only execute once until that either changes or becomes null. If that's not possible, is there a compromise?

Thanks ahead to anyone who attempts to help,
Appreciate it!

**Edit:**
So I don't think I gave enough info so here is the code for the server getting the info from the game state:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile('player_team', 'utf8', function(err, teamStatus) {
    var player = 'player' in req.body ? req.body.player : null;
    if (player && player.team !== teamStatus) {
      var newTeamStatus = req.body.player.team;
      if (!newTeamStatus) {
        newTeamStatus = '';
      }
      fs.writeFile('player_team', newTeamStatus);
      console.log(newTeamStatus);
    }
  });
});

var PORT = 8080;
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
app.listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log('Server is running on ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
```

Comment: the logic in `checkTeam` is not very clear, especially in the `if (teamStatus === 'T'){` block. You seem to have very different logic if teamStatus is T compared to teamStatus == CT - not sure exactly what the required outcome is to be honest

Comment: I will edit the post with the server code that is pulling the game state from the game.

Comment: why? that doesn't explain what logic you're *trying* to achieve

Comment: teamStatus is either CT or T (The two teams in CS:GO) so the server sets those values.

Comment: still not explaining what you want to achieve on the client - is it simply, if you're on CT turn on a blue light, if you're on T turn on an orange light, otherwise turn off all lights - and only console if the team changes?

Comment: Pretty much, but sometimes the light that changes flickers on and off really quickly, leading to me thinking that the same thing making console.log('CT Side'); is also making the light flicker. So I was wondering if I could make the If statement execute only if the teamStatus changes. - Like I said, I'm very new so I may have no clue what I'm talking about. :D

Comment: There is a bug in this code I think, you should probably use `setTimeout` and call it manually at the end of the callback once the file is read , because `fs.readFile` or even `fs.readFileAsync` could cause an overlap and end up start behaving weirdly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what I can guess of the logic, you might want to do:

```
var currentStatus = '';
function checkTeam() {
    fs.readFile('player_team', 'utf8', function (err, teamStatus) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (teamStatus !== currentStatus) { // only change lights if status has changed
            if (teamStatus === 'CT') {
                console.log('CT Side');
                changeLight(3, noLights()); // turn off 3?
                changeLight(1, blueLights());
            }
            else if (teamStatus === 'T') {
                console.log('T Side');
                changeLight(1, noLights()); // turn off 1?
                changeLight(3, orangeLights());
            }
            else {
                changeLight(1, noLights());
                changeLight(3, noLights()); // 1 and 3?
            }
            currentStatus = teamStatus; // update the current status
        }
    });
}
```

The only thing I can't figure out is what the `1` or `3` in changeLight does, so this code may be incomplete, however I believe it does what your original code does without flickering the lights or console.log what team you are on every 250ms

I've added some comments to lines I think may be needed if there are two different lights one of which goes blue or the other goes orange